# [ROS 2] Machine Learning Tutorial

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I did the following tutorial, with Ubuntu 18.04 and ROS2

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_setup/

And I am doing the following:

https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_machine_learning/

All ok, but, in the item 24.2.1 Set State:(https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/ros2_machine_learning/#set-state?

I can't find the file: turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.gazebo.xacro
are only the files turtlebot3_burger.urdf and others .urdf files.

Can you help me, please. Where is the file or how can install or create it.

Thank you.

Regards.

EDS

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355988/%5Bros-2%5D-machine-learning-tutorial/) by [EDS](https://answers.ros.org/users/56218/eds/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

The issue is that the `turtlebot3/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.gazebo.xacro` is only used for ROS1 versions of the package. You can find the `.gazebo.xacro` files in any of the [ROS1 branches of the turtlebot _description](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/melodic-devel/turtlebot3_description/urdf/turtlebot3_burger.gazebo.xacro) package.

For ROS2, the gazebo simulation of TB3 is changed to  `.sdf` files, by default those are stored in `turtlebot3_gazebo/models/`.

The turtlebot3_burger model file is [`turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf`](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/ros2/turtlebot3_gazebo/models/turtlebot3_burger/model.sdf).  All the plugin configurations are done there.

Hope this helps!

---

Originally posted by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) with karma: 802 on 2020-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [EDS](https://answers.ros.org/users/56218/eds/) on 2020-06-29**:
Hello Mario, thank you for your answer. was ok!

**Comment by [Mario Garzon](https://answers.ros.org/users/568/mario-garzon/) on 2020-06-30**:
That's great.   Then can you mark the answer as correct?